# Why too long variable names causes 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The next line of code caused `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`:

```
#coding=utf-8    
result_3_logspace_mean_proportion_сorrect_answers = Exception('3_logspace_mean_proportion_сorrect_answers').get_result(result_1_main)
```

while the second line of code not:

```
#coding=utf-8
result_3 = Exception('3_logspace_mean_proportion_сorrect_answers').get_result(result_1_main)
```

How to deal with the problem? I strongly want the first variable name.

Comment: It’s possible that the problem is actually in the line above.  Perhaps a bracket was not closed?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that variable name.

Comment: I get a SyntaxError with the first line in Python 2, but not in Python 3

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It's validated, I have the same behavior.

Comment: Python 2 doesn't allow arbitrary Unicode like that non-standard `с` in variable names. That's why that specific character is highlighted.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Probably because you copy-pasted the code from this question. I typed in and didn't get a syntax error in either versions of Python. I bet that one of the characters is a unicode character. You didn't get the error in Python 3 since in Python 3 allows unicode characters in names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The letter at the beginning of `correct` is not a `c`, it's a Cyrillic `с`, and Python 2 only accepts ASCII by default in source code.

Answer (score 4):

The first variable name contains a non-ascii character: the first "c" in "correct" is a [small cyrillic es](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/441/index.htm). You can see this if you decode the string to ascii:

```
#Python3
>>> 'result_3_logspace_mean_proportion_сorrect_answers'.encode()
'result_3_logspace_mean_proportion_\xd1\x81orrect_answers'

#Python2
>>> u'result_3_logspace_mean_proportion_сorrect_answers'.encode('utf8')
'result_3_logspace_mean_proportion_\xd1\x81orrect_answers'
```

Substituting it for a normal "c" fixes the issue.